# How to prove the formula of eligibility traces operator in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proofs, bellman-equations, eligibility-traces

[image]

I don't understand how the formula in the red circle is derived. The screenshot is taken from [this paper](http://www.marcgbellemare.info/static/publications/harutyunyan16qlambda.pdf)

Comment: I recently got wondering about pretty much the same question as well. How can, for example, Q-Learning work using Auto-Differentiation when a constant is subtracted from an output of the actual Q-Network, i.e. predicted Q-Value, to compute an update of the predicted Q-Value (given that constants are commonly dropped during differentiation)? That is: why is the baseline estinate/constant, i.e. the part not being dependent on the policy network, not dropped during differentiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will refer to $\mathcal T^{\pi} $as $\mathcal T$ and $P^{\pi}$ as $P$ for notational simplicity
\begin{align}
(\mathcal{T})^{n+1} Q &= \mathcal{T}(\mathcal{T}(...(\mathcal{T}(Q))))\\
&= r + \gamma P(r + \gamma P(...(r + \gamma P Q)))\\
&= r + r\sum_{i=1}^{n} \gamma^i P^i + \gamma^{n+1} P^{n+1} Q
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\mathcal{T}_{\lambda}Q &= (1-\lambda) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lambda^n (\mathcal{T})^{n+1} Q\\
&=(1-\lambda)\{\lambda^0 (\mathcal T)^1Q + \lambda^1 (\mathcal T)^2Q + \lambda^2 (\mathcal T)^3Q + \ldots   \}
\end{align}

when you plug in expression for $(\mathcal T)^i Q$ inside this sum and rearrange you get 3 sums
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{T}_{\lambda}Q = (1-\lambda) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lambda^n r + (1-\lambda)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda^n \gamma^n P^n r + (1-\lambda)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lambda^n \gamma^{n+1} P^{n+1} Q
\end{equation}

1. sum:
   \begin{equation}
   (1-\lambda) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lambda^n r = r
   \end{equation}
2. sum:
   \begin{equation}
   (1-\lambda)\sum_{n=1}^{k} \lambda^n \gamma^n P^n r = (1-\lambda\gamma P)^{-1}(1 - \lambda^k \gamma^k P^k)\lambda\gamma P r
   \end{equation}
   As $k \rightarrow \infty$ and since $\gamma < 1$ this is in the limit equal to
   \begin{equation}
   (1-\lambda)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda^n \gamma^n P^n r = (1-\lambda\gamma P)^{-1}\lambda\gamma P r
   \end{equation}
3. sum:
   \begin{equation}
   (1-\lambda)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lambda^n \gamma^{n+1} P^{n+1} Q = (1 - \gamma\lambda P)^{-1}(1-\lambda)\gamma P Q 
   \end{equation}
   If you combine all 3 you get
   \begin{align}
   \mathcal{T}_{\lambda}Q &= r + (1-\lambda\gamma P)^{-1}\lambda\gamma P r + (1 - \gamma\lambda P)^{-1}(1-\lambda)\gamma P Q\\
   &= r+ (1-\lambda\gamma P)^{-1}(\lambda \gamma P r + \gamma PQ - \lambda\gamma PQ)\\
   &= r+ (1-\lambda\gamma P)^{-1}(\lambda \gamma P r + (\mathcal T)Q - r - \lambda\gamma PQ)\\
   &= (1-\lambda\gamma P)^{-1}(r - \lambda \gamma P r + \lambda \gamma P r + (\mathcal T)Q - r - \lambda\gamma PQ)\\
   &= (1-\lambda\gamma P)^{-1}( (\mathcal T)Q  - \lambda\gamma PQ + Q - Q)\\
   &= Q + (1-\lambda\gamma P)^{-1}( (\mathcal T)Q  - Q)
   \end{align}

Comment: Add some properties about Markov chain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain